# Unable to use stringstream to read in int and double

Tags: c++, stringstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>//for istringstream

int main(){
    
    std::istringstream iss;
    std::string tempSTR;
    int A;
    double B;
    std::cout<<"Please enter an int.\n";
    std::cin>>tempSTR;
    iss.str(tempSTR);
    iss>>A;
    std::cout<<"A = "<<A<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"Please enter a double.\n";
    std::cin>>tempSTR;
    iss.str(tempSTR);
    iss>>B;
    std::cout<<"B = "<<B<<"\n";

    std::cout<<"\nEND OF PROGRAM. GOODBYE!\n\n";
}//end of main
```

Code is simple enough but it just won't work. I just need to use a string stream to read in an int and then a double. Reading in the int first works but the double just gets outputted as zero. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `iss.str(tempSTR)` resets the stream's contents, but doesn't clear flags like EOF. Try `iss.clear()` after `iss.str(tempSTR)`, or use a separate instance each time and don't attempt to reuse the same one. Or, just skip `istringstream` altogether and do `std::cin >> A` and `std::cin >> B`; it's unclear why you want an intermediate string representation to begin with.

Comment: Even easier would be to forget about istringstream and use the functions `stoi` and `stod` which convert a string to an int and a double directly, without the need for string streams.

Comment: alright this question is answered. Just out of curiosity though, @IgorTandetnik wouldn't it be better to use one stringstream and just clear it each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
``
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>//for istringstream
//Using stringstream to read in multiple arguments
int main(){
    
    std::istringstream iss;
    std::string tempSTR;
    int A;
    double B;
    std::cout<<"Please enter an int.\n";
    std::cin>>tempSTR;
    iss.str(tempSTR);
    iss>>A;
    iss.clear();
    std::cout<<"A = "<<A<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"Please enter a double.\n";
    std::cin>>tempSTR;
    iss.str(tempSTR);
    iss>>B;
    iss.clear();
    std::cout<<"B = "<<B<<"\n";

    std::cout<<"\nEND OF PROGRAM. GOODBYE!\n\n";
}//end of main
``
//Question:Unable to use stringstream to read in int and double
//Answer:stream just needed to be cleared before using it to read in another argument.
```